# Unit Testing Local Notifications

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, unit-testing, uilocalnotification

I've spent the last day or so trying to figure out a way to unit test my local notifications.

I'm using Swift 2.2 and Xcode 7.3

Essentially, I have a stripped down API which generates `UILocalNotification`, which are triggered via `UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow`

In my `AppDelegate` I have implement the `application:didReceiveLocalNotification` method to show a `UIAlertController` as follows

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    if application.applicationState == .Active {
        var topController : UIViewController = (application.keyWindow?.rootViewController)!

        while ((topController.presentedViewController) != nil) {
            topController = topController.presentedViewController!
        }

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: notification.alertTitle, message: notification.alertBody, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction!) in}))

        topController.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

When running this manually, this works fine. I can see the messages generated and the alert displayed.

What I want to do though is provide a unit test to verify this functionality.

My experience with testing iOS is non-existent.

My first thought was to mock the `UIApplicationDeledgate` in some way so I can test to see if the `application:didReceiveLocalNotification` was called, something like `UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate = mockedDelegate`, when I tried to do this it crashed.

My next thought was to use a UI test and monitor for the alert dialog.  This worked to a point, I was able to register for notifications (and get the "Allow notifications" dialog, which I was able to tap through using the `XCTestCase` API), but the notification was presented as a banner, not as an alert (from within the application itself)!?

At this point I'm at a loss as to what to try next.

I'm currently not using any mocking frameworks, and my understanding is Swift doesn't lend itself well to them, but this is just from my reading (unless I'm willing to extend from `NSObject`).

Answer (score 0):

You can test the delegate method by creating a local notification and calling it directly in your test like this:

```
let notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.alertBody = "Attention!"
var userInfo  = [String: String]()
userInfo["name"] = "notification"
notification.userInfo = userInfo
// further notification setup

let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate
appDelegate?.application!(UIApplication.sharedApplication(), didReceiveLocalNotification: notification)
```

You can invoke other delegate methods similarly to test notification actions, etc.